# Bootstrap tr:hover background-color adding little square

Tags: html, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table which have the table-hover class attached.

I have overwritten that class to the following:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

The table code is the following:

```
<div class="row mt10">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="position_absolute width100p height300">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover position_absolute height300" ng-if="sheet !== undefined;" style="display:block;">
                <tbody class="height300" style="overflow-y: auto; display: block;">
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in sheet track by $index" class="width100p">
                        <td class="width125 height40 scrollableX" style="white-space: nowrap;" ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">
                        {{ col }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem appears when the mouse enters a `<td>`, because is adding a little square to the top-left of the `<td>`.

Something like this:
[image: Problem with table tr]

Do you know what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide your code

Comment: Add HTML, so we know how your structure is, do you use bootstrap? Because they already have a hover effect on their tables

Comment: I have added the html code @dippas

Comment: not able to reproduce your problem